# create a strings file for a custom storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am localizing my app, and I have a custom storyboard I created called Into.storyboard. When I added a language to the app, it gave me an option to create strings files for Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard, but not for my custom storyboard. How do I create one so that it automatically fills in the object IDs like it did for the other two storyboards? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the right side inspector you can find button `localize`. Press it and choose languages.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CRow.jpg)